# Within Google Cloud, how can I set publish permissions for PubSub per function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am currently working on a GCP project, where I need to try and achieve the following.

I need to somehow restrict which GCP functions can publish to which GCP topics?

Does anybody have any ideas how I could achieve this?,

Thanks,

Tom Early

Comment: In your question, by "function" do you mean "Cloud Function" or "functions" as a programming concept?  Can you perhaps provide some additional context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Functions runs as [PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam#runtime_service_account) and has the permissions of that service account. Therefore if you want different functions to have different permissions, you will have to create them in separate projects. For example you could have:

- Function `abc` in project `abc-proj`
- Function `xyz` in project `xyz-proj`
- Pub/Sub topics `a-topic` and `z-topic` in project `pubsub-proj`
- Grant `projects.topics.publish` permission on topic `a-topic` (in `pubsub-proj`) to `abc-proj@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`
- Grant `projects.topics.publish` permission on topic `z-topic` (in `pubsub-proj`) to `xyz-proj@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`

And you will then have function `abc` able to publish to `pubsub-proj/a-topic` and function `xyz` able to publish to `pubsub-proj/z-topic`, but not cross-wise.

Comment: Thank you David! This is exactly what I have tried and it works a treat :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you wish to publish a message, you specify the topic where you will publish this message. This means the message will only be published to that particular topic and no other topics. You can have a look at documentation related to publishing messages [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher) if you need further help with publishing a message to a particular topic.

Answer (score 0):

Since I still have no reputation to do so (sorry about that), I am writing a new answer just to let everyone that might come across this know that the answer by David is also valid for Cloud Run by simply replacing the service account by the one that is handling your Cloud Run service.

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest Cloud Functions doc [1], the Cloud Functions service uses the `Google Cloud Functions service agent` service account (`service-PROJECT_NUMBER@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com`).

So, if you need the additional permissions beyond the default settings. You can bind additional roles to that service account.

And make sure the service account has permission to publish to the Pub/Sub topic [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam#cloud_functions_service_account
[2] https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam#troubleshooting_permission_errors

Hope this helps ~:)